# Compiling HelloWorld.cs Issue

Tags: c#

so I just decided to learn C#, I am using some lessons from a guy called Bob Tabor, so I am in the 1st tutorial, here is the link so you can see what he is doing and what am I doing. ITS THE SAME!

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Creating-Your-First-C-Sharp-Program

1.Created my HelloWorld program on notepad (there is no need but I am following the tutorial) [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DscnL.png]

2.Tested the c# compiler

3.Tried to compile it 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDgRL.png]

4.Get the error????

What am I doing wrong? please help
Using Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010

Answer (score 12):

You are using forward slashes. They should be backslashes

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU I noticed that in the video but though it doesnt matter, thank you very much

Comment: @user2544354 Did you get it working? If so mark as answer (but I think you have to wait 10 min after post)